# Jenkins 2.150.3 update is not overwriting the previous version

Tags: jenkins

I already have Jenkins 2.150.1 installed, so I tried downloading the new version (2.150.3). However, after installing and restarting, it's still loading the previous version.

In the notifications, it says that version 2.150.3 is available. When I click and download Jenkins.war version 2.150.3 and install it the terminal using `java -jar jenkins.war`. As expected, it installs the new version, and then I close the terminal.

When I restart the PC or Jenkins, it's loading the old version of Jenkins again.

How do I update Jenkins without deleting the current jobs and having to re-install any plugins?